# IPrincipal cannot be found in dnxcore50

Tags: dnx, iprincipal, project.json

I try to use IPrincipal in dnxcore50. Although it works fine on Windows, I get the following error when running `dotnet restore` on OS X:

> Unable to resolve System.Security.Principal (>= 4.0.1-rc3-23829)
>   for DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (osx.10.11-x64).

My `project.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.3-*",

  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": false
  },  

  "compile": "*.cs",
  "exclude": "Platform/**/*.cs",

  "frameworks": {
    "net45": {
      "include": "Platform/DotNet45/*.cs",
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Xml": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Xml.Linq": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Xml.XDocument": "4.0.0.0"
      }   
    },  
    "dnxcore50": {
      "include": "Platform/DotNetCore/*.cs",
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.0.0-rc3-23829",
        "System.Security.Principal": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms": "4.0.0-beta-23225",
        "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates": "4.0.0-rc3-23829",
        "System.Xml.XDocument": "4.0.11-rc3-23829",
        "System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.0.11-rc3-23829"
      }   
    }   
  }
}
```

It seems that System.Security.Principal is only available on the Windows platform, but the concept of IPrincipal seems pretty generic too me. The NuGet page (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Principal/4.0.1-beta-23516) also doesn't list dnxcore50 as a dependency, but only the "old" .NET frameworks.

Comment: Made any progress after asking this question?

Comment: To be honest... I gave up on CoreCLR until things are a bit more stabilized. Currently, it's a big mess due to incompatible versions and different toolchains. That's a shame, because the idea for CoreCLR is great, but the current implementation and version issues made me bail out...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use IPrincipal anymore for dnxcore50 projects, but rather derive from ClaimsPrincipal. You can learn more about this here: https://player.vimeo.com/video/154041158